# Выбрать часть строки через regexp

Tags: javascript

Необходимо вытащить родительский элемент из ссылки путем удаления ненужных фрагментов через .replace.
Адреса могут быть любые, любой длины и с любыми символами (цифры и буквы). Поэтому ориентируюсь на .* и слеш.

На данный момент есть адрес следующего вида:
page1/page2/page3/ . Нужно чтобы остался page2
Код вида:

```
str = str.replace(/.*\//, '');
```

удаляет все. 
Код вида:

```
str = str.replace(/\/.*/, '');
```

оставляет только page1

В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: а какие варианты входной строки еще бывают, и что их них надо взять?

Answer (score 2):

Может, без регулярок: разбить по слешам на массив?

```
var str = 'page1/page2/page3/';

var parts = str.split('/'); // ['page1','page2','page3','']

// в parts убираем последний элемент.
// в случае пустого последнего элемента pop() делаем дважды
if( !parts.pop().length) parts.pop();

// теперь в parts последним элементом – нужный «родительский»
// вытаскиваем его через тот же pop():
var parent = parts.pop(); // 'page2'
```

Comment: "Нужно чтобы остался **page2**".

Comment: Ваше решение помогло очень. Конечный результат легко можно довести до нужного через .replace. Решение в целом вышло не самое красивое, но главное, что работает. Спасибо!

Comment: Обновил ответ: `.replace()` не нужен, три строки, сплошные `pop`'ы : )

Answer (score 2):

```js
// Берём 2-ую с конца часть (1 часть - от слеша до слеша)
console.info(`page1/page2/page3/`.replace(/.*\/([^\/]+?)\/[^\/]+?\/?$/i, `$1`)); // page2
console.info(`some/thing/other/remove`.replace(/.*\/([^\/]+?)\/[^\/]+?\/?$/i, `$1`)); // other

// Без регулярок.
// split - разбиваем по слешам
// filter - убираем пустые элементы (если в конце слеш, будет пустая часть в конце)
// slice - берём 2 последних элемента
// shift - берём первый из них, т. е. второй с конца всей строки
console.info(`page1/page2/page3/`.split('/').filter(e => e).slice(-2).shift()); // page2
console.info(`some/thing/other/remove`.split('/').filter(e => e).slice(-2).shift()); // other
```

Comment: Помогло! Очень развернуто и красиво. Спасибо!

Comment: @gam1et22, всегда пожалуйста, выберите устраивающий Вас ответ как принятый.

Answer (score 2):

Еще один вариант с [`match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match)

```js
document.write('page1/page2/page3/','->','page1/page2/page3/'.match(/\/([^/]+?)\/[^/]+?\/$/)[1],'<br/>');
document.write('page1/page2/page3/page4/','->','page1/page2/page3/page4/'.match(/\/([^/]+?)\/[^/]+?\/$/)[1],'<br/>');
```